# How to query BigQuery view through Datalab?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datalab

I have a SQL View Saved in my BigQuery. I wanted to run SQL queries on this View. WE can run SQL Query on Tables as follow :

```
%%bq query
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE condition
```

But I am getting error while running the same for View:

```
%%bq query
SELECT * FROM viewname
```

Error:

> invalidQuery: Cannot reference a legacy SQL view in a standard SQL query.

OR

```
import google.datalab.bigquery as bq
c = bq.View.query(sql='SELECT * From viewname').execute().result().to_dataframe()
```

Error:

> NameErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
>        in ()
>             1 import google.datalab.bigquery as bq
>       ----> 2 c = View.query(sql='SELECT * From viewname').execute().result().to_dataframe()
>   TypeError: 'property' object is not callable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have already identified there are two ways of working with BigQuery in Datalab:

- Using **%%bq**, as presented in [this sample notebook](https://github.com/googledatalab/notebooks/blob/991fba5b26b4cb2651e7d7c50ab65afeb5761219/tutorials/BigQuery/Hello%20BigQuery.ipynb).
- Using **Datalab's BigQuery API libraries** ([sample notebook](https://github.com/googledatalab/notebooks/blob/master/tutorials/BigQuery/BigQuery%20APIs.ipynb)). Currently, the supported and updated version is `google.datalab.bigquery`, however the legacy version `datalab.bigquery` is still available for backwards compatibility reasons.

As per the error message that you are getting ( `Cannot reference a legacy SQL view in a standard SQL query` ), I understand that the view you are querying was created with a Legacy SQL query. As explained in this post, [Datalab is moving to Standard SQL](https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab/wiki/%60datalab%60-to-%60google.datalab%60-Migration-Guide), and therefore its support for Legacy SQL is being discontinued. That is the reason why both `%%bq` and `google.datalab.bigquery` do not support Legacy SQL, and only work with Standard SQL.

If you really need the view as it is right now (i.e. created with Legacy SQL), as a temporary workaround, you can use the old library instead (which is still available), `datalab.bigquery` as below:

```
import datalab.bigquery as bq
bq.Query("SELECT * FROM dataset.legacy_sql_view;").results()
```

However, I would strongly recommend that you start [migrating to Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql), given that it is the preferred query language for BigQuery, and it has multiple advantages, among which you can count the official support in Datalab.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks for your answer dsesto. Was really helpful.

Comment: I am glad I could help!